# jQuery capture the change event of a dropdown when change is performed by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-1.7

I would like to be able to detect when the selected value of dropdown has changed using jQuery. The selected value of the dropdown is changed by other JavaScript, so I want to be able to catch this event.

I can see the dropdown changing, however the following code does not capture the event correctly. Does the `change` event only capture the event when it is performed by the **user** and not other code?

```
$('select[name=b_country]').live('change', function() {
    alert('the country dropdown has changed');
});

<select name="b_country" style="display: block;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only user interactions fire the event. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to (re)set values in a listener without entering an infinite loop.

If you want to inform other (listening) scripts that you changed the value, you can manually trigger an event. With jQuery, this is easy:

```
$('select[name=b_country]').val(…).change();
```

Comment: The problem I have here is that the code that changes the `b_country` dropdown is not mine. It is third party JavaScript and I don't have any control over it. Is there no other way to capture when it is changed?

Comment: No. If that third party script doesn't offer a proper API (to hook on events like this, etc), I'd recommend to use another one.

Comment: That's frustrating. I would have thought you could have listened on a specific element in the DOM and when it changed state, by any means, you could capture the change.

Comment: The API I am using doesn't document the callbacks, however their support channel has advised that they do exist. This allowed me to implement the feature I needed.

Comment: Uh, using undocumented features is like a hack ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure how much I agree with the statement that "using undocumented features is like a hack". I am using valid API code and JavaScript, so it's not really a hack. My hands are tied with regards to the fact that the callbacks are undocumented, so there's nothing I can really do about that. I am frustrated that the technology provider doesn't provide documentation to the callbacks, but they did provide suitable support and the callbacks themselves work.